# Refused to load the script '<URL>' in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, content-security-policy

I know how CSP works, and strangely enough it for a while after I load my unpacked my chrome extension for the first time.

It's only after a while that the errors start pouring in. Let's get to the point, I use Firebase as my database storage, and I added the following CSP.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.firebaseio.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

This is the error I'm receiving

> Refused to load the script 'https://test-2c95a.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=4598235&cb=1&v=5' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround for this?